# Find orthonormal basis of quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-multiplier

Q: Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
3 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find the quadratic form of $q: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ represented by A.

and find an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which q has a diagonal form.

-
So far I managed to find the quadratic form and used lagrange to get the following equation.

Quadratic form: $3x_1^2-2x_1x_2+2x_2^2-2x_2x_3+3x_3^2 = 0$

using lagrange I got:

$3(x_1-\frac{1}{3}x_2)^2 +1\frac{8}{9}x_2^2+(3x_3^2-2x_2x_3)^2 =0$

$$y_1 = x1-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$y_2 = x_2$$
$$y_3 = x_3 - \frac{1}{3}x_2$$

meaning the base should be:

$$x_1 = y_1 + \frac{1}{3}$$
$$x_2 = y_2$$
$$x_3 = y_3 + \frac{1}{3}y_2$$

$$B = \left\{\left(1, \frac{1}{3},0\right), (0,1,0), \left(0, \frac{1}{3}, 1\right)\right\}$$

But that didn't fit when I tried to multiply A with the basis to find the diagonal form.

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have to do it the way you did? You could try to directly diagonalize orthogonally $\;A\;$ . I think your decomposition using completion of squares is wrong.

Comment: how can I directly diagonalize orthogonally ? by elemntary operations ? I tried that as well.. couldn't get the right solution too

Comment: No, you can diagonalize orthogonally by eigenvectors, Gram Schmidt and all that.

Comment: @Joanpemo Eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are already orthogonal, so at most all that’s needed is normalization. You shouldn’t have to go through the whole G-S process.

Comment: Thanks @amd. I know that, and I didn't go through G-M below. Just wanted to mention the general process in the diagonalziation cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing squares I get, with $\;x,y,z\;$ instead of $\;x_i\;$ :

$$3x^2-2xy+2y^2-2yz+3z^2=3\left(x-\frac13y\right)^2+\frac43y^2+3\left(z-\frac13y\right)^2\implies$$

$$\implies \begin{cases}I\;\;\;\;\,a=x-\frac13y\\II\;\;\;b=y\\III\;c=z-\frac13y\end{cases}\;\;\;
\implies\;\;\begin{cases}x=a+\frac13b\\y=b\\z=c+\frac13b\end{cases}$$

So the base part is $\;\left(1,\,\frac13,\,0\right)\;,\;(0,1,0)\;,\;\left(0,\,\frac13,\,1\right)\;$ , and the quadratic can be expressed as

$$\color{red}{q(a,b,c)=3a^2+\frac43b^2+3c^2}$$

Observe that the eigenvalues of $\;A\;$ are

$$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x-3&1&0\\1&x-2&1\\0&1&x-3\end{vmatrix}=$$
$$=(x-2)(x-3)^2-2(x-3)=(x-3)(x-4)(x-1)$$

with eigenvectors:

$$\begin{align*}
&\bullet\;\lambda=1:\;\;\begin{cases}-2x+y\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=0\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;y-2z=0\end{cases}\implies2x=2z=y\implies&\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}\\{}
&\bullet\;\lambda=3:\;\;\begin{cases}\;\;\;\;\;\;y\;\;\;\,\;\;=0\\x+y+z=0\end{cases}\implies x=-z\,,\,y=0\implies&\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\!-1\end{pmatrix}\\{}
&\bullet\;\lambda=4:\;\;\begin{cases}x+y\;\;\;\;\;\;=0\\\;\;\;\;\;\,y+z=0\end{cases}\implies x= z=-y\implies&\begin{pmatrix}\;1\\\!-1\\\;1\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}$$

Now orthonormalize the above three vectors, form the matrix $\;P\;$ whose columns are the new vectors and check that

$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&4\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, @amd. I just wanted to show the general method, I shall correc now.

Comment: Why "orthonormalize" instead of "normalize" in your last sentence? The vectors already form an orthogonal basis due to the spectral theorem and the symmetry of A.

Comment: @Maxence1402 I didn't assume all along the OP knows what the Spectral Theorem is and what it says. The above is in general...and, of course, if the matrix is symmetric, as in this case. then we can save a whole lot of work. I am guessing the OP basically knows about Gram - Schmidt Theorem and perhasp not more than that.